# How to use case statement in select with termsql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm getting an unexpected error when using a case statement with a query using [termsql](https://tobimensch.github.io/termsql/). Is there something I'm doing wrong with it, perhaps invalid sql, or might this be an issue with the termsql parser ([sqlparse](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/) version 0.4.2)?

Here's a simplified example of what I'm seeing (with newlines to help readability):

```
echo "Fred|10\nJulie|15\nFatima|42\nJulie|10\nFatima|18" | \
termsql -c 'name,activities' -t test -d'|' \
"select case name when 'Fatima' then 'Primary' else 'Secondary' end primary_normalized,sum(activities) from test group by primary_normalized"
```

That yields and error of:

```
Error: near line 1: near "'Fatima'": syntax error
```

The goal there is to group things by "Primary" and "Secondary" based on a chosen name.

This same query will do it, but the output isn't quite what I want:

```
echo "Fred|10\nJulie|15\nFatima|42\nJulie|10\nFatima|18" | \
termsql -c 'name,activities' -t test -d'|' \
"select name,sum(activities) from test group by case name when 'Fatima' then 'Primary' else 'Secondary' end"
```

The output from that is

```
Fatima|60
Fred|35
```

...which is kind of weird since the select is operating on the name field, but the group is operating on the case statement output. Not unexpected, but not desirable, where I'd really like the first option to work.

Comment: Your query is syntactically correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ac90af96e6808ee3ed6c1d95321fc894 You mention that the code yo provide is *a simplified example*. So the issue is your actual code which you should post.

Comment: @forpas Thanks for confirming my sql syntax, that helps! Regarding the "simplified example", I just meant simplified in the sense that it shows the same problem I am having, just with a few sample records meant to avoid unnecessary distraction from the issue. The code/terminal examples here do function and do exhibit the error.